# SQL Server combine case with convert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi im stuck with this query, what i want is to get one column "fecha_registro_convertida" with the condition of the case statement but also with the CONVERT statement so i can get the date converted properly with the case statement

```
SELECT top 50 rs_IDCliente idCliente, CONVERT(datetime, 
           SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
                                c.rs_fecharegistro), 
                        DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) 
   AS fecha_registro_convertida,
CASE WHEN rs_fecharegistro IS NULL THEN c.CreatedOn ELSE rs_fecharegistro END 
          rs_fecharegistro, 
          isnull(BirthDate, '19900101') fechaNacimiento,
          suc.rs_IDSucursalregistro AS SucursalRegistro
FROM NMP_MSCRM.dbo.contact c
INNER JOIN NMP_MSCRM.dbo.rs_sucursalregistro suc
ON c.rs_SucursalRegistro=suc.rs_sucursalregistroId
```

[Image of the records that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdHyc.png)

Comment: FYI, `CASE` is an *expression* not a statement, T-SQL doesn't support `Switch` (`Case`) statements, and `CONVERT` is a **function**.

Comment: As for your question, I really don't follow what you are asking (you don't actually ask anything). What is your question? What about your code isn't working? Also note that a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and that row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using `TOP` you need to ensure the query has an `ORDER BY` so that you get consistent and reliable results.

Comment: Your case statement looks to be doing the job of an IsNull.  Perhaps what  you want is `ISNULL ( CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, c.rs_fecharegistro), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))), c.CreatedOn )`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What i want is like to combine the expression CASE within CONVERT function so my record of date is going to be converted and also have the condition of the case expression. Something like:
`SELECT top 50 rs_IDCliente idCliente, CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, CASE WHEN rs_fecharegistro IS NULL THEN c.CreatedOn ELSE rs_fecharegistro END rs_fecharegistro), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS fecha_registro_convertida`

Comment: Please share minimal data, and table definitions (as TEXT, or as a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019)). The sample data should be minimal, and have the situations that you are having troubles with...   And, of course, the desired output that this sample data should produce.

Comment: Hi, i attached an image of the records that i got with the original query. I got two columns named fecha registro convertida and fecha registro, i just want one column fecha_registro_convertida. That column should be the output from the query that i want, i.e, the expression CASE inside the function CONVERT, but i dont know how to handle that query i mean how to combine those sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL as posted delivers 5 columns: `fecha_registro_convertida, fecha_registro_convertida, rs_fecharegistro, fechaNacimiento, SucursalRegistro`.

Based on the comments, you want to have just 4 columns in the result: `fecha_registro_convertida, fecha_registro_convertida, fechaNacimiento, SucursalRegistro`.

Again based on comments, I believe you want `fecha_registro_convertida` to be the result of a `SWITCHOFFSET` on the column `rs_fecharegistro` or (if the value of `rs_fecharegistro` is null) on the column `c.rs_fecharegistro`.

This is quite easy to solve, by using `ISNULL` within the `CONVERT` function.  I.e. replace

```
CONVERT(datetimeoffset, c.rs_fecharegistro)
```

with

```
CONVERT(datetimeoffset, ISNULL(c.rs_fecharegistro, c.CreatedOn))
```

Based on those assumptions, the SQL you need could be:

```
SELECT top 50 
     rs_IDCliente AS idCliente
    ,CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, ISNULL(c.rs_fecharegistro, c.CreatedOn), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS fecha_registro_convertida
    ,ISNULL(BirthDate, '19900101') AS fechaNacimiento
    ,suc.rs_IDSucursalregistro AS SucursalRegistro

FROM       NMP_MSCRM.dbo.contact c
INNER JOIN NMP_MSCRM.dbo.rs_sucursalregistro suc
        ON c.rs_SucursalRegistro=suc.rs_sucursalregistroId
```

(Note that is has been pointed out by @Larnu in the comments that the resulting rows are indeterminate because you have a `TOP 50` restriction without an `ORDER BY` clause - but I am not trying to solve that issue).